# Compare Records and display the column name which are having different values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the sample table what I have. I have multiple err# one among is Err# 2

```
Err#    ItemNo  Price   Company   Model
2       101     50      ABC       A12
2       101     50      ABC       A12
2       101     50      ABC       A13
2       102     30      XYZ       B1C
2       102     40      ZYZ       B1C
2       103     80      MNO       AL5
2       103     90      MNR       AL9
```

Er# 2 - I am getting an error message as "Same ItemNo having different values from other columns" Ideally it shouldn't have different values for same ItemNO.

What it mean is ItemNo 101 Price is same, Company is same in all the 3 records, but Model is different it has both A12 and A13 which is wrong.

Whenever we have the same ItemNo has different value it should show me the column name which is having differet values as per the Item No.

O/P should be

- For All 101 Records It should Print as - Same ItemNo having Different Model Value
- For All 102 Records It Should Print as - Same ItemNo having Different Price, Company
- For All 103 Records It Should Print as - Same ItemNo having Different Price, Company Model

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select itemno,
       substr( (case when min(price) <> max(price) then ',price' end) ||
               (case when min(company) <> max(company) then ',company' end) ||
               (case when min(model) <> max(price) then ',model' end),
               2) as columns_with_differences               
from t
group by itemno;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works, but however I need this to print for all the records (101 3 records same result), not only for one item 101.    Also what if have more than 50 columns is there any alternative way I can do it easily. Please suggest

Comment: @Puttu . . . This does the work for all items.  If you have many columns, then construct the query in a spreadsheet and copy it over.